# Enabled boot logging option in Win XP doesn't produce ntbtlog.txt file

Tags: windows-xp, boot, logging

I have tried enabling the boot logging option for Windows XP Pro using the F8 and also *boot.ini* method, but it does not seem to be creating the expected *ntbtlog.txt* file. I'm doing this to help me solve a problem where the Avast antivirus service is not starting up - it keeps complaining with the message: "Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start".

I seem to notice that the file is produced on a system where the Avast antivirus is starting up without any problems. Can anybody suggest why the *ntbtlog.txt* file is not being created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `ntbtlog.txt` is not getting created on your system on which Avast is unable to run is likely due to the fact that it uses a driver which is not starting. Drivers are loaded early in the boot process and `ntbtlog.txt` isn’t written until the session manager runs, which occurs *after* the drivers are loaded. So if Avast’s driver is causing a problem, then the boot-log may not get written. I had a similar problem a while back and found an MS [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275735) that gave a clue to the reason. Of course it doesn’t help solve the problem.

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to view the installed drivers (reduce the clutter by selecting verify and hide). You should see one or more Avast related drivers. If you disable them and reboot (selecting the boot-log option), you should get the file.

The next step is to figure out how to fix Avast—short of just reinstalling it. (Of course you’ll want to re-enable the its drivers.)

Run `Services.msc` and open the Avast service(s) and switch to the *Dependencies* tab and look at the top box. It should show you what services or drivers it depends on. That will help narrow down what’s causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me some idea on where to start. The file seems to be created after I disabled all the Avast drivers at startup.